# How does a message look on an Android phone?

Tags: iphone, messages, android

I have an iPhone but no Android phone. When I send a message to a friends Android phone, I am always nervous that I use some function that is not supported.

Is there somewhere online where I can see what a message looks like on an Android phone, or a list of supported functions?

**Examples:**

I shared the location of a pizza place via a message to an Android phone. The location is not received, but the phone number of the place!

I send a birthday message with balloons, and a normal message with some appended text saying "Balloons" is received - I forgot exactly how it was.

Some emojis are not supported - but which?

A picture is received in a bad resolution - but how bad?

Related:
[iPhone-Android texting compatibility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66533/iphone-android-texting-compatibility)